# Como faço para que apareça loading enquanto a página estiver carregando com Semantic UI?

Tags: html5, css3, front-end, semantic-ui

Bem, eu acabei de ver no site do semantic o tópico de carregamento, onde a vários tipos de loadings, mas fiquei com dúvida de como eu faria para que quando o conteúdo estivesse sendo carregado ficasse com esse loading e quando estivesse totalmente carregado ele perde-se o loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você adicionar o loading com html

```
<style>
    * {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    html, body, #loader {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #loader {
        background: #000 url('https://loading.io/spinners/flask/index.svg') no-repeat center center;
    }
</style>

<div id="loader"></div>
```

E basta utilizar o evento `onload` para verificar quando os elementos foram carregados.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = "none";

    alert("carregado");
};
```